# How to create a spring object mid-method?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

In the old pre spring version I had something like this:

```
public String jobRun(int projectID)
{
    JobHelper jobHelper = new JobHelper(projectID); 

    jobHelper.this();
    jobHelper.that();
}
```

How can I create the JobHelper object using spring?  I made it a spring component, but it can't be global.

I guess I want something like this:

```
public String jobRun(int projectID)
{
    @Autowired
    @Scope("prototype")
    JobHelper jobHelper;    

    jobHelper.this();
    jobHelper.that();
}
```

However, that's not how spring works.

Thanks,

Comment: Spring components are what you'd call "global" by default. They should generally be stateless singletons. If you need stateful objects (In this case, your state is `projectID`), they should generally not be Spring managed. Just because you're using Spring doesn't mean everything should be a Spring managed bean.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I don't really want it to be managed by spring. However, I want to us autowiring in the JobHelper itself.

Comment: Probably you need to specify a bit more clearly what you want to do. Do you have one `JobHelper` globally, or do you want multiple ones (one for each `projectId`? If the latter ist the case how should the Springframework find out which of these multiple instances should be autowired?

Comment: Autowiring is used _for_ Spring beans. You can't autowire something that isn't a Spring managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, you need to let Spring now that `JobHelper` is "Autowireable". It'd be like this for the class where you need `JobHelper` to do things:

```java
public class YourClass{

    @Autowired
    JobHelper jobHelper;    

    public String jobRun(int projectID){
        jobHelper.this();
        jobHelper.that();
        return "something";
    }

}
```

And JobHelper itself would be like

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class JobHelper {    

    public void this(){}

    public void that(){}

}
```

Injection is a broad topic, so I'd suggest you read guides/articles such like this [on @Autowired](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) or this [on @Component](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-annotation) from Baeldung for a start.

Comment: Would this use the same jobHelper for all methods in my class, right?  It would basically be global.

Comment: In that example the JobHelper would be a Spring managed Singleton.